# How to limit data only to logged in user in Entity Framework Core Identity Easily

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core Identity. All my Entities have a property called `CreatedBy`, a Foreign Key to the built in Identity `User` table. I have a `GetAll()` endpoint in my API that returns all records from the tables associated with these entities. I want this `GetAll()` to only return records that were created by the currently logged in user. I can get the `UserId` from the `HttpContext`, but I was wondering if I could automatically limit the records.

For example, I can perform an action like this to get this behavior:

`return _context.Entities.Where(e => e.UserId == userIdFromHttpContext).ToList()`

However this is some extra condition I would have to put in every single `Where` clause in every single future `Get` method I'd write. This is highly redundant to me.

I would like to simply just call

`return _context.Entities.ToList()`

which would automatically filter all the records out not associated to the currently logged in user.

Is there anything I can do, to configure some sort of "automatic" pre-defined where clause in the `DbContext` that applies to all tables in the context, just once? Preferably I'd like to inject the `HttpContext` into the `DbContex`t (I know this can be done) and configure this behavior in the `OnConfiguring()` method there.

edit: I'd like to avoid a wrapper around the class around the context if possible as well. This application is being worked on by college students and I'd like them to use the "vanilla" `Entity Framework` conventions for grabbing data as opposed to working with some sort of custom implementation

Answer (score 4):

you could use a Global Query Filter (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters))
In a nutshell, you can specify a Where during the call to OnModelCreating, and it will be applied every time you try to access that entity collection.